# How to create a list environment with automatic pauses in beamer?

Tags: beamer, animations

I would like to make my bullet lists appear as follows.

```
* First
  * Second
  * Second
  * Second
* First
  * Third
  * Third
    * Fourth
    * Fourth
  * Third
* First
```

Id est the first slide shows the overall outline and then each slide shows the outline of a bullet.
The motivation is to display hierarchical proofs, firstly explaining the main idea, then proving each point, then each subpoint…

I guess a solution would be to replace the `enumerate` (or `itemize`) environment with a custom one, inserting `\pause` automatically when needed but I am not sure on how to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Admittedly not fully automatic but probably nevertheless useful, at least as a starting point:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\onslide<+->{\begin{itemize}
  \item First 
    \onslide<+->{\begin{itemize}
      \item Second
      \item Second
      \item Second
    \end{itemize}}
  \item First
    \onslide<+->{\begin{itemize}
      \item Third
      \item Third
    \end{itemize}}
  \item First
    \onslide<+->{\begin{itemize}
      \item Fourth
      \item Fourth
    \end{itemize}}
  \item First
\end{itemize}}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\only<+->{\begin{itemize}
  \item First 
    \only<+->{\begin{itemize}
      \item Second
      \item Second
      \item Second
    \end{itemize}}
  \item First
    \only<+->{\begin{itemize}
      \item Third
      \item Third
    \end{itemize}}
  \item First
    \only<+->{\begin{itemize}
      \item Fourth
      \item Fourth
    \end{itemize}}
  \item First
\end{itemize}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The result is indeed the expected behaviour, thank you. I'll try to automate it

Comment: I am not sure to understand why `\newenvironment{anitemize}{\onslide<+->\begingroup\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}\endgroup}
` does not work

Comment: @Blincer The braces in `\only<+->{...}` delimit an argument of `\only`, they do not form a group. To delimit an argument, you have to use braces. Try the `environ` package. It defines the command `\NewEnviron{name}{...\BODY ...}`. When you do `\begin{name}...\end{name}`, the contents of the environment is collected into `\BODY`, which you can use in the replacement text. You can try something like `\NewEnviron{anitemize}{\onslide<+->{\begin{itemize}\BODY\end{itemize}}`.

Comment: I'll take a look at that package, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I konw that this is the question about Beamer. Sorry. Please, silently ignore my answer. But I want to add another solution of your task in OpTeX, for code readability comparison only.

```
\slides
\slideshow

\null
\layers 5
* First
  \begitems \pshow2
  * Second
  * Second
  * Second
  \enditems

* First
  \begitems \pshow3
  * Third
  * Third 
    \begitems \pshow4
    * Fourth
    * Fourth
    \enditems
  \enditems

* First
\endlayers

\pg.
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to specify the desired `<slide range>` just after every  `\item` or alternatively  with `\begin{itemize}[<slide range>]`. The example below does not behave exactly as you asked to show more alternatives that just `<n->` after every item (all the needed in this case), but you can adapt easily (just doing as in the items of the first level).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=10} % adjust or remove if you want
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize} 
\item<1-> First 
    \begin{itemize}[<+-|structure@+>]
    \item Second 1
    \item Second 2
    \item Second 3
    \end{itemize}
\item<1-> First
    \begin{itemize}[<3->]
    \item Third 1
    \item Third 2
        \begin{itemize}
        \item<4-|alert@+> Fourth
        \item<4-|alert@+> Fourth
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\item<1-> First
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You can use also the slide specification in other environments as well as in some commands as  `\only`,`\visible`,`\uncover`, `\color`, etc. to more complex effects, but some to  remember is that like the items of my example, `\visible` or `\uncover` show an  argument that is there in all the slides (always taking space), whereas `\only` take space "only" when is showed. What is better depends on the contents:`\only` can save some space that you need for other elements but can have the undesired effect of "dancing items" whereas `\visible` cannot move anything, and with some transparency before and/or after the slide, you can focus the actual item while allowing to review past items, and check that if the actual item is really the final item of the topic (create false expectations of ending whatever is fatal for presentations after the 10th slide, and even earlier; you are warned).